# Java: Regular Expressions and string.replace()

Tags: java, regex, parsing

Code:

```
expression = "1x^2+6x+9";

expression = expression.replace("^n", ""); //n represents a number
expression = expression.replace("x", "");
```

Intended Result:

```
expression = "1+6+9";
```

Given a polynomial expression, I want to remove the variable terms (in this case, x^2 and x). Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
expression = "1x^2+6x+9";
expression = expression.replaceAll("x(\\^\\d)?", "")
```

Comment: Doesn't change the string :/

Comment: Of course it does not. Strings are immutable in java. You have to assign it to some variable

Comment: I still don't understand.

Comment: what exactly you do not understand?

Comment: I still don't understand how to resolve the issue. I'm a relatively new programmer so I don't understand your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You may use replaceAll with regx -

```
String newPlynm = plynm.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]", "");
```

Hope it will help.
Thanks a a lot.